# WPF UserControl transparent regardless of the Background property

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make a control with transparent background, but I would like the Background property to define some inner controls background. So that i can use background property.

Usually I just bind background to the UserControl background. But then how to have the whole control background transparent regardless of the Background property.

```
<UserControl 
x:Class="HLab.Base.DateEx"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:base="clr-namespace:HLab.Base"
mc:Ignorable="d" Background="Transparent">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Calendar.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <Style TargetType="base:NumTextBox">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#80000000"/>

        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <base:NumTextBox 
            x:Name="TextDay"
            MinValue="0"
            MaxValue="31"
            Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Background, Mode=OneWay}"
            ValueChanged="OnValueChange"
        /><Popup 
            Name="Popup" 
            StaysOpen="False">
            <Calendar 
                Name="Calendar" 
                SelectedDatesChanged="Calendar_OnSelectedDatesChanged"/>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>

    <base:NumTextBox 
        Margin ="3,0,0,0"
        Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Background, Mode=OneWay}"
        x:Name="TextMonth" 
        Grid.Column="2"
        MinValue="0"
        MaxValue="12"
        ValueChanged="OnValueChange"
        />

    <base:NumTextBox 
        Margin ="3,0,0,0"
        Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Background, Mode=OneWay}"
        x:Name="TextYear" 
        Grid.Column="3"
        MinValue="0"
        MaxValue="9999"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        ValueChanged="OnValueChange"
        />

    <Button 
        Margin ="3,0,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Grid.Column="4"
        Name="Button" 
        Width="15"
        Click="Button_OnClick"
        Background="Transparent">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Calendar}"/>
                </Grid>
           </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
    <Border  
        x:Name="Mandatory" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="1"  
        Visibility="Collapsed" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="#10FF0010" IsHitTestVisible="False" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="0.5" BorderBrush="DarkRed"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="IconMandatory" 
            Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed" 
            Grid.Column="0"  
            Margin="5,0,0,0" 
            IsHitTestVisible="False" 
            Content="{StaticResource Edit}" Foreground="DarkRed" Height="15"/>
</Grid>
```

if I use it :

```
<DateEx Background="Red"/>
```

I would like the button not to get red background, but only NumTextBoxes.

Comment: Create a custom template or use another property.

Comment: We need to see a full example of your code.

Comment: I added an example, another property would break all code where this is used.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change something like this, you'll have to modify the `ControlTemplate` of your control.

`UserControl` is usually used when you just have a bunch of existing controls you want to group together with a bit of logic. But when you need even more customizability you need what's called a "custom control". "Custom controls" inherit directly from `Control` (instead of `UserControl`) and require you to create a default `Style` with a `ControlTemplate`.

The full official documentation is here: [Control authoring overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview). There's *a lot* there, but maybe you can pick out the information and examples you actually need.
For a simpler walk-through there is also this: [WPF - Custom Controls - Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_custom_controls.htm) (scroll down to the "Custom Control" heading).